# Table referencing multiple tables. Error in save "Referential integrity constraint violation."

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I have tables in the following structure.

Table1 **Key, DocKey,** Name

Table2 **Key, DocKey,** Name

Table3 **Key, DocKey,** Name

Table4 **Key, DocKey,** T1Key, T2Key, T3Key, Name, Value

I have defined the foreign key relation ship in the following way. What i am trying to do is, to make the T4 dependent and have navigational properties to T1, T2 and T3.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Table4>()
                     .HasRequired<Table3>(d => d.Table3Nav)
                     .WithMany()
                     .HasForeignKey(k => new { k.DocKey, k.T3Key });

modelBuilder.Entity<Table4>()
                     .HasRequired<Table2>(d => d.Table2Nav)
                     .WithMany()
                     .HasForeignKey(k => new { k.DocKey, k.T2Key });

modelBuilder.Entity<Table4>()
                     .HasRequired<Table1>(d => d.Table1Nav)
                     .WithMany()
                     .HasForeignKey(k => new { k.DocKey, k.T1Key });
```

I am able to add objects, but when i am trying to save, i am getting the following error. tried searching through similar errors, but unable to figure out what need to change. Please assist.

Save

```
 public int SaveDoc(Doc Document)
        {
            if (Document.Key == 0)
                data.Docs.Add(Document);
            else
            {
                var currDoc = data.Docs.Where(x => x.Key == Document.Key).FirstOrDefault();
                data.Entry(currDoc).CurrentValues.SetValues(Document);
            }
            data.SaveChanges();

            return Document.Key;
        }
```

> Referential integrity constraint violation. A Dependent Role has
>   multiple principals with different values.

Comment: Try setting `WillCascadeOnDelete(false)` for all `modelBuilder.Entity<Table4>` definitions. Which code that attempts to add (and save) new objects?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, added that but still gives the error. I have updated the question to include the saving. is anything need to be done there? I am adding and deleting entities in the Business logic before i send the object to the save function.